# Нет кнопки "Delete" на странице плагинов Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Хочу удалить плагин, но не могу сделать это через стандартную кнопку Delete, так как её нет((
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но удалить можно с помощью кнопки Bulk Actions->Delete предварительно выделив нужный плагин для удаления.
Ах да, чуть не забыл, при обновлении страницы плагинов - кнопка появляется и резко исчезает....

Comment: Проверьте права пользователя и права на папку с плагинами

Comment: @Даниил спасибо, проверил, но ничего не поменялось...

Comment: Если кнопка появляется и исчезает, попробуйте почистить кеш браузера. Если бы зависело от прав пользователя, то вы её вообще не видели бы. У меня была подобная ситуация в хром, я зашел с yandex browser - все норм, после чего ресетнул настройки хрома с отключением всех экстеншинов

Comment: Поищите в инспекторе, возможно какой-то css конфликтует и ставит ей display:none;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на незаданный вопрос.

Виноваты плагины безопасности или настройки в конфиге.

Comment: подскажите подробнее, какие настройки в конфиге могут на это влиять ?